# .htaccess afflict URL but not local data, without RewriteEngine

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following problem:

If I open my site at page `example.com/foo/bar` each stylesheet is loaded like this:
Source:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But my server loads this file like: `foo/css/style.css`

Now I want to change my `.htaccess` `RewriteEngine` that this does not happen, **however** I *don't* want to use a `RewriteRule` which prevents `/css/` to change `URL`!

My `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?urlparam=$1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using relative paths in your css, js, images files rather than an absolute one.

You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Thank you, this was realy helpfull

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to `example.com/foo/bar` it is interpreted as a resource `bar` in the directory `/foo`. Your markup is including `css/style.css` and since it does not contain a leading `/`, it means the `css` folder is relative to the current path (which is `/foo`). So that is why you are seeing the behavior.

Your rewrite rules have nothing to do with what is happening. If you navigate to `example.com/foo/bar/` (trailing `/`) then it would request `example.com/foo/bar/css/style.css`.

Comment: Is there a possibility to stop the script acting like this?

Comment: You could use an absolute path to your CSS file instead of relative.

Comment: This is not possible for me.